# Qt: Architectural advice needed regarding QAbstractScrollArea

Tags: qt

I'd like to design a scrollable "controls container" widget. Meaning, a scrollable view that'll be able to contain live controls (any QWidget derivative). By "live controls" i mean, if a animated QWidget derived is placed in it, i'd like to see the animation, as i scroll up and down, while the sub-control moves up and down.

Would basing such a widget on "QAbstractScrollArea" be the right way to approach it? i'd simply add controls as children? positioning them in a column? will that be enough?

**EDIT:**

This is the constructor code from my QAbstractScrollArea derived class. Why don't I ever see a scrollbar that can scroll the controls? (not all are visible on the same page based on the height I gave my control)

```
// add controls


    QPushButton *a = new QPushButton(QString("a"), this);
    a->setGeometry(QRect(10,10,100,30));
    QPushButton *b = new QPushButton(QString("b"), this);
    b->setGeometry(QRect(10,40,100,30));
    QPushButton *c = new QPushButton(QString("c"), this);
    c->setGeometry(QRect(10,70,100,30));
    QPushButton *d = new QPushButton(QString("d"), this);
    d->setGeometry(QRect(10,100,100,30));
    QPushButton *e = new QPushButton(QString("e"), this);
    e->setGeometry(QRect(10,130,100,30));
    QPushButton *f = new QPushButton(QString("f"), this);
    f->setGeometry(QRect(10,160,100,30));
    QPushButton *g = new QPushButton(QString("g"), this);
    g->setGeometry(QRect(10,190,100,30));
    QPushButton *h = new QPushButton(QString("h"), this);
    h->setGeometry(QRect(10,220,100,30));

    this->addScrollBarWidget(new QScrollBar(this), Qt::AlignRight);
    setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOn);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, that is enough.  Use the concrete QScrollArea class and a generic container widget, then position your controls as children of the container.

```
QScrollArea scrollArea;
QWidget container;

// Create controls and add them to container.

scrollArea.setWidget( &container );
```

Comment: The code doesn't work. when i "setWidget" my entire container disappears and stays invisible. Without it, i can see it, but no scrollbars. using qt 4.7.4 on Mac.

Comment: The [documentation](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qscrollarea.html#setWidget) says "If the scroll area is visible when the widget is added, you must show() it explicitly."  It also says you must set the container widget's layout before `setWidget` is called.  Sorry, I did not know this before.  Hope that works!